# in what situations will ni% in top is not 0

Tags: linux, cpu, top, priority

I learnt that ni represents the cpu used for userspace processes whose niceness or priority value is changed, but in my system, which is CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core), I did below test, all the test result is that, ni is always 0. Could anyone help me understand when will ni% change?

ProNoChange is a simple process to consume some cpu.

scenario1:

```
  taskset -c 31 ./PriNoChange 50 &

  taskset -c 31 nice -n -10 ./PriNoChange 50 &

  taskset -c 31 chrt --rr 50 ./PriNoChange 50 &
```

result:

[image: top result of 3 processes]

scenario2:
change the niceness in code by setpriority and then run the process, still ni is 0

```
  int which = PRIO_PROCESS;
  id_t pid = getpid();
  int ret;
  int priority = -10;
  ret = setpriority(which, pid, priority);
```

[image: change niceness by setpriority]
thanks,
Russel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man 1 top`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html#2._SUMMARY_Display):

> `ni`, `nice`    : time running niced user processes

"Niced" should be interpreted as "nicer than default", i.e. "with niceness greater than the default `0`". You did not observe niced processes because `-10` in your example is *less* nice, it does not count as niced.

E.g. this counts as niced:

```
nice -n 1 md5sum /dev/urandom
```

Comment: Thank you Kami, I used nice -n 10 to run my process, and it counts ni%